# Type arguments do not conform to trait type parameter bounds

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-deequ

I am using a library which is written by amazon in scala [here](https://github.com/awslabs/deequ/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/amazon/deequ/analyzers/Analyzer.scala#L56)

The trait goes like this :

```
trait Analyzer[S <: State[_], +M <: Metric[_]]
```

I am trying to make a case object to store some information and an instace of the above Analyzer is a part of it.

```
case class AnomalyCheckConfigBuilder(anomalyDetectionStrategy: AnomalyDetectionStrategy,
                                     analyzer: Analyzer[_, Metric[_]],
                                     anomalyCheckConfig: Option[AnomalyCheckConfig] = None)
```

I'm getting the below error :

```
error: type arguments [_$1,com.amazon.deequ.metrics.Metric[_]] do not conform to trait Analyzer's type parameter bounds [S <: com.amazon.deequ.analyzers.State[_],+M <: com.amazon.deequ.metrics.Metric[_]]
       case class AnomalyCheckConfigBuilder(anomalyDetectionStrategy: AnomalyDetectionStrategy,
```

Not sure, what's the problem here. Does anyone understand this?

Comment: What is the `State` and `Metric` types of you analyzer?

Answer (score 2):

The thing is, if you look at the definition of `State` trait, you will see `trait State[S <: State[S]]` which means the type inside the State type argument (named S), MUST be a subtype of State of that type, for instance: `trait MyState extends State[MyState]`. but using underscore in `analyzer: Analyzer[_(this one), Metric[_]]` does not assure the compiler that this type extends State of that type. to make the compile error go away, you can do:

```
case class AnomalyCheckConfigBuilder(anomalyDetectionStrategy: AnomalyDetectionStrategy,
                                     analyzer: Analyzer[_ <: State[_], Metric[_]],
                                     anomalyCheckConfig: Option[AnomalyCheckConfig] = None)
```

which is shorter form of

```
case class AnomalyCheckConfigBuilder[StateType <: State[_]](anomalyDetectionStrategy: AnomalyDetectionStrategy,
                                     analyzer: Analyzer[StateType, Metric[_]],
                                     anomalyCheckConfig: Option[AnomalyCheckConfig] = None)
```

Comment: Since you helped on this, can you help on this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71297290/inferred-type-arguments-1-do-not-conform-to-method-type-parameter-bounds