# Inferred type arguments [_$1] do not conform to method type parameter bounds

Tags: scala, generics, amazon-deequ

I have a case class :

```
case class AnomalyCheckConfigBuilder[S <: State[S]](anomalyDetectionStrategy: AnomalyDetectionStrategy,
                                                    analyzer: Analyzer[S, Metric[Double]],
                                                    anomalyCheckConfig: Option[AnomalyCheckConfig] = None)
```

And i have a function which returns a collection of the above case class objects in the form of a Seq.

```
val anomalyCheckConfig : Seq[AnomalyCheckConfigBuilder[_]] = jobConfig.validate.get.getAnomalyCheckConfigBuilder
```

I am adding the objects from the above list to another method who's signature is below :

```
def addAnomalyCheck[S <: State[S]](
      anomalyDetectionStrategy: AnomalyDetectionStrategy,
      analyzer: Analyzer[S, Metric[Double]],
      anomalyCheckConfig: Option[AnomalyCheckConfig] = None)
    : this.type
```

I am doing the below operation :

```
anomalyCheckConfig.foreach(x=>{
            verificationSuite = verificationSuite.addAnomalyCheck(x.anomalyDetectionStrategy,x.analyzer,x.anomalyCheckConfig)
          })
```

Where verificationSuite is a opensource code from [Deeque](https://github.com/awslabs/deequ/blob/db63229e83bf60da0f7cff323f081b2490578b38/src/test/scala/com/amazon/deequ/VerificationSuiteTest.scala#L264)

Error i am getting on the above code is :

```
error: inferred type arguments [_$1] do not conform to method addAnomalyCheck's type parameter bounds [S <: com.amazon.deequ.analyzers.State[S]]
[ERROR]             verificationSuite = verificationSuite.addAnomalyCheck(x.anomalyDetectionStrategy,x.analyzer,x.anomalyCheckConfig)

error: type mismatch;
[ERROR]  found   : com.amazon.deequ.analyzers.Analyzer[_$1,com.amazon.deequ.metrics.Metric[Double]]
[ERROR]  required: com.amazon.deequ.analyzers.Analyzer[S,com.amazon.deequ.metrics.Metric[Double]]
[ERROR]             verificationSuite = verificationSuite.addAnomalyCheck(x.anomalyDetectionStrategy,x.analyzer,x.anomalyCheckConfig)
```

The code fails on compile time and scala is unable to understand the state, and i am unable to understand where is `_$1` coming from. Would appreciate some inputs on thiss

Comment: Try using this in your class definition: `case class AnomalyCheckConfigBuilder[S <: State[_]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This clearly says that Scala needs you to provide an instance of `'S'` which is a subtype of `State` class.

What you need to do is :

```
anomalyCheckConfig.foreach(x=>{
            verificationSuite = verificationSuite.addAnomalyCheck[S](x.anomalyDetectionStrategy, x.analyzer.asInstanceOf[Analyzer[S, Metric[Double]]], x.anomalyCheckConfig)
          })
```

Also you need to wrap this under a function which accepts `S` as a subtype of `State`

```
    def anmomaly[S <: State[S]](){
    
        anomalyCheckConfig.foreach(x=>{
                    verificationSuite = verificationSuite.addAnomalyCheck[S](x.anomalyDetectionStrategy, x.analyzer.asInstanceOf[Analyzer[S, Metric[Double]]], x.anomalyCheckConfig)
                  })
}
```